ASP .NET MVC app restarts after SignalR websocket crashes
My question is twofold. One is, why does the entire server crashes after SignalR websocket crashes and why does SignalR websocket crashes.
.Net framework 4.8
ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library 2.4.3
Jquery 3.6.0
In development environmentthis problem does not exits. When user connects we also use JoinGroup them in SignalR after this there are 2 scenarios where the websocket crashes.
Scenario 1: Multiple users connects and does nothing. This involves a few messages initially, but after that the pages stand idle (no messages while idle). After a while (tested it with 30-60min) if we close one of the connection, we get LeaveGroup and OnDisconnect, but after that the websocket crashes and the app restarts.
Scenario 2: Single user does regular expected work on the page, which includes messages frequently. In this case the crash can happen rather fast, after a few mins, but it is very inconsistent.
Both scenarios look the same in the logs. Scenario 2 runs LeaveGroup and OnDisconnect, and similarly after that the socket crashes and the app restarts.
This is a new behaviour, we have been testing SignalR for awhile now and we dont know what makes it crash suddenly, especially when its idle. I cant reproduce this issue in dev environment so I am really having trouble figuring out why the websocket crashes and I have no idea why does that restart the entire app.
Update: We tested scenario 2 further. There seems to be a correlation between the crash and sessionstate timeout. After closing one of the connections, there is a delay between that and the crash and time increases if you increase sessionstate timeout.
